# What are the rules for subclassing accessing static members?

Tags: java, static, subclass

I was fooling around with static members, I got confused when something compiled that I didn't think should:

```
class ClassA {
    static String s = " ";
}

public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    private ClassB() { 
         s = "I feel like this shouldn't be possible."; 
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        new ClassB();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

I don't understand how ClassB can access the static member on ClassA. My understanding was that static information is kept with the class it's declared on, and isn't passed down into subclasses. Is that an incorrect assumption, or is the compiler doing something sneaky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not specifying an access modifier makes a member available to the whole `package`. Statics are class-scoped, but that doesn't mean you can't access them from the outside.

If you'd make it `private`, you wouldn't be able to access it.

Comment: A useful link is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html. It has a nice little table showing the relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Static information is absolutely not kept in the class it is declared on. Standard access control rules apply to every static member defined for a class. This means you can apply the `private`, `protected`, `package protected` (your case) and `public` access control modifiers to all static members of class (this includes methods).

See what the JLS has to say about access control: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#104285

Answer (score 0):

In class B you actually set s on ClassA, not its instance. The line in your constructor is equivalen to

```
private ClassB() { 
         ClassA.s = "I feel like this shouldn't be possible."; 
    }
```

You can however omit "ClassA" because you access it from derived class.